# Can a Homography be used when images are slightly different?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have two pictures of a mole, but second picture is slightly different from the first because mole has changed its form a bit. Both images have different perspective, so I am willing to compute a homography to transform the second image's perspective to the first one's perspective.
I know it could be done when images are the same but perspective is not, but can it be done when images are slightly different?